# Not intended reset listview and spinner on tab change

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I got a tab with 3 fragments, the  first tab and the thirth tab has both a listview and the second tab has a listview with a spinner as part of the item row. When I have populated the listview and switch tabs the listview resets on both first and second tab. As I got the thirth tab keep updating the listview when it's selected(up to date. Score list) should I do this for the other 2 tabs aswell? Or is there a trick to keep them from reseting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just set         `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);`

This way you will keep 2 tabs away from current loaded and in your case, all 3 tabs will remain loaded and will never be recreated (updated).